# How to translate conditional string interpolation using NGX-translate

Tags: angular, ngx-translate

I have a toggle button on my application that changes the label accordingly to its value, it will either display 'Enabled' or 'Disabled'.
I'm using *ngx-translate* to handle translation on my application but I can't get this to work. How can I set the translation in this scenario?
The words "disabled" and "enabled" should be translated.

`{{ toggleRedirect ? 'Disabled' : 'Enabled' }}`

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use *translate pipe*  : {{ toggleRedirect ? 'Disabled' : 'Enabled' | translate }} ...but you should check if the 'Disabled' & 'Enabled' are on the translation file (ie en.json) and your config for ngx-translate is correct